# regular expression for numeric digit starting with '$' sign

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a regular expression to validate these type of string formats:

```
$-1000.999
$9999.444
-12344.555
123434.55
0.444455
```

Also is there any good tool to make regular expressions?

Comment: Check out [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) and/or [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\$?\-?(([1-9]{1})([0-9]*)|0)(\.[0-9]*)?$
```

please check.. this matched your test cases.

Comment: This is good, except it will match strings like `123.` with no digits after the decimal point.  Is that valid?  Also, you've got a lot of parentheses you don't need, and the `{1}` is just taking up space.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regular expression : `\$?-?\d+\.\d+`

Comment: Read as "1 or 0 dollar signs, 1 or 0 hyphens, followed by a string of digits, a period, and another string of digits"

Answer (score 0):

```
\s+$?(-+)?\d*\.?\d*\s+

one or more spaces followed by
zero or one $ sign followed by 
zero or one of either - or + followed by
zero or more digits followed by
zero or one decimal followed by
zero or more digits followed by 
one or more spaces
```

This will match numbers like .444455 and 11111 as well and will not match @223.44 or #444.33 or &1233.555

Comment: try this `($)?(-+)?\d*\.?\d+` instead, it doesn't expect a mandatory decimal rather it expects 0 or 1 decimal

Comment: it pass this string why? #11111

Comment: because numeric part of the string matches the regular expression. If you just want a number try `\s+($)?(-+)?\d*\.?\d*\s+`

Comment: No i just want string may only start with $ sign.like these both are valid $111.000 and 134.555. but this should not valid like start with other charactor @223.44 or #444.33 or &1233.555 these are not valid